# How to get the currentTime of Video which is running on <object> html tag?

Tags: javascript, html, html4

I'm working on a TV App which is limited to **HTML4** and I want to use an `<object>` tag for displaying video, but I've been looking for a way to get the **currentTime** of the video!

Comment: How `<object>` tag looks like ? Post some code, please.

Comment: For the other hand take a look to this code snippet: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_av_prop_currenttime

Comment: thanks, but your code is using `<video>` tag, I wanna use `<object>` tag. 
Something like this: `<object width='100%' height='100%' type='video/mp4' data='SampleVideo.mp4'></object>`